# IE10 Hyperlink on click shifting upwards

Tags: html, css

in IE10 facing issue where when clicking on a hyperlink the link shift upwards positionally and when leave the click it comes back to position, preventing the click event from occurring and so the link being followed.

I checked in Hyperlink 
 is used this works fine in all other browsers except IE10... How to fix?

```
<a href="foo.html"><br /><br />Dev G <br/></a>
```

Comment: paste your appropriate JsFiddle link to your code here

Comment: I don't have the problem in IE 10

Comment: not able to replicate in fiddle :( but in code it happening I also read one article in which as well they mentioned same issue https://coderwall.com/p/see6ma

Comment: not happening on each IE10 link

Comment: Works fine on IE10, I've checked. There's something else cooking, paste or code or provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this post (I know its old) but I had the same error if compatibility mode is turned off, the solution is to place the `<br />` tags outside of the `<a>` tag:

```html
<br /><br /><a href="foo.html">Dev G</a><br/>
```

Turn compatibility mode on and it works fine.